# manage device back button in android fragment for soft key board

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext, onbackpressed

I having some problem in device back button. I am creating a fragment and making the layouts "VISIBLE" and "GONE" to get the values in steps.
Like instead of creating 5 fragments i created on fragment and playing with the visibility of the layouts to have values. I have 5 steps (5 layouts). 
Now i am trying to control the device back button. 
Having the problem with the layout which have Editext in it. If i don't touch Editext then the back button management is working fine but when i tap on Edittext to enter the value then on tapping the back button it exits the fragment. 
I think soft keyboard is taking the control of back button. 
Behavior should be that when i tap the back button then it will exit the keyboard and then on again pressing the back button, it should not exit the fragment and it should give the control to the layout management which i am doing in the fragment.

Here is the code for back button management.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                if (genderLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You wanna Exit the Fragment Here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                        return true;
                    }
                } else if (dobLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                 dobLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    genderLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
                } else if (heightLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    heightLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    dobLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
                } else if (weightLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    weightLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    heightLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
                } else if (excerciseLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    excerciseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    weightLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }


            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Now how i can manage the back button for the layout which have Edittext on it.